# AppSync API, authentication method and how to refresh x-api-key

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, api, aws-appsync, api-key

I am coding a react native app, without user authentication.
The app shows a list of cards (like apartment cards in airbnb) using GraphQL API and AWS AppSync.

AppSync provides different authentication methods, but I can't choose the best one for production.

- Everyone (without authentication) could use the app

I am using api-key auth method in production, but the api key expires in 7 days... How can I update the app in production with a new api key each time? (Maybe it's not the correct auth method for production)

I saw many apps the are using x-api-key header in their network traffic, refreshing it each 10 minutes... how they do that?